# How to add filter in fluentd

Tags: filter, docker, fluentd, openshift-origin

Our fluentd configuration looks like this:

Input:

a `fluentd/configs.d` folder which contains

- input
- filter
- output

Inside input we have two .conf files which are defining our sources:
This is one of the .confs

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @label @INGRESS
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/es-containers.log.pos
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
  tag kubernetes.*
  format json
  keep_time_key true
  read_from_head true
</source>
```

The other config has the same label `@INGRESS`

In our filter section we have some config's to filter on all the sources from `@INGRESS`. The output section defines what to do whith our filtered logs.

our global fluentd.conf looks like this:

```
## sources
@include configs.d/input/docker/*.conf
@include configs.d/input/syslog/*.conf
##

<label @INGRESS>
## filters
  @include configs.d/filter/k8s_meta.conf
  @include configs.d/filter/kibana_transform.conf
  @include configs.d/filter/k8s_flatten_hash.conf
  @include configs.d/filter/k8s_record_transform.conf
  @include configs.d/filter/syslog_record_transform.conf
##

## matches
  @include configs.d/output/operations.conf
  @include configs.d/output/applications.conf
##
</label>
```

So it's all inside the `@INGRESS` label and this is working fine.
But now we want another filter on our the same 2 sources. This filter will also have an outputfile (to tell what to do with the filtered logs). But we only want THAT filter, not the other filters which are inside the `@INGRESS` section (in fluent.conf).

It's not possible to add 2 labels to a source and add a label in our `fluent.conf` file.

So what is our solution to add an independent filter and output file on the same source as the source for everyting with the `@INGRESS` label?

Thanks.

[This](https://github.com/openshift/origin-aggregated-logging/tree/master/fluentd) is the github repo with the sourcecode we are using for our fluentd.